# SQL EXCEPTION : conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[anyvalue]' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception

I am working with Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 and I have a table
`bookdat` with these columns:

```
title varchar(200), author varchar(100), publication varchar(200),
accno varchar(200) not null primary key, price int, quantity int
```

Now in Visual Studio I am creating a search database function where, user can search any data by using any one column(from a checkbox), and entering the value in a textbox to find that data in the database table.

This functionality works well when i am searching for accno, price and quantity.
But it throws exception when searching for title, author, publication.

I have even tried converting the values to string or int accordingly (using `convert.tostring` etc.), it didn't work.

My C# code is here (b/w I have declared `SqlConnection con`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` in form public class):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bookdat WHERE title=@fdata OR author=@fdata OR publication=@fdata OR accno=@fdata OR price=@fdata OR quantity=@fdata", con);

        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 3)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 4)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 5)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count> 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Found!!");
                comboBox2.Text = "";
                textBox8.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Records Found!!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill The Required Fields To Find Data !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a bunch of nested if statement that all do exactly the same thing? That should be a single statement. But in reality your code is never going to work because you are using a single parameter to search across various datatypes. You really should be using a different parameter for each searchable property. Then using a catch-all type of query to find the data. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ And definitely be careful using AddWithValue...http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Sami I wasn't;

Comment: A downvote to my question, why ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT * FROM bookdat WHERE");


       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con);

        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
            sb.Append(" title=@fdata ");
        }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
            sb.Append(" author=@fdata ");
            }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
            sb.Append(" publication=@fdata ");
            }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
            sb.Append(" accno=@fdata ");
            }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata",int.Parse( textBox8.Text));
            sb.Append(" price=@fdata ");
            }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata",int.Parse( textBox8.Text));
            sb.Append(" quantity=@fdata ");
            }
        cmd.CommandText  =sb.ToString();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count> 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Found!!");
                comboBox2.Text = "";
                textBox8.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Records Found!!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill The Required Fields To Find Data !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer. Just a bunch of code without any explanation. And no one should be recommending the use of AddWithValue because that is part of the problem - see [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: No problem with that, another method can be used to add parameters

Comment: and this way, ain't working, exceptions remains the same.

Comment: Exceptions are caused by the use of AddWithValue
You can change it to
cmd.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("@ parameterName", value));

Comment: محمدالنعيمي   Yea, your coding way worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I marked your solution as the best answer, as its more straight a way and easy to understand.
Just a change, you made this statement wrong : cmd = new SqlCommand(con);
it was showing overload method match error, bcuz according to the method it need a string statement too. so you can make here the changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is on these kind of lines:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
```

The implicit conversion fails, so convert it to int

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text));
```

You will have to ensure that textBox8 has text in it.

Anyway you seem to be having a lot of logic to accomplish a task that would be much easier to solve.

Your `if` statement , for example, could be much more cleaner:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 3 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 4 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 5)
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", textBox8.Text);
}
```

Comment: Using this way, i am getting this exception now :
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @FrazzerK is it the same exception?

Comment: No, this one is different from the one i was facing earlier.

Comment: and which is this one?

Comment: Exception : Input string was not in a correct format.
pointing to this line :
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdata", Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text));

Comment: This is no better than what the OP was trying to do. They are using the value of textBox8 to search for both string and numeric values. The approach the OP is taking is problematic to say the least.

Comment: @SeanLange is there any way to solve this problem, maybe doing within the if statements ...?

Answer (score 0):

There is still a lot of guesswork here because we don't know the table structure or much of the details but here is how I would approach this.

First step is to create a stored procedure that can find the data from bookdat based on the various columns. Something like this should work. Please notice the RECOMPILE option. See the article in my original comment for details about why this is so important here.

```
create procedure bookdat_Search
(
    @title varchar(50)
    , @author varchar(50)
    , @publication  varchar(50)
    , @accno int
    , @price int
    , @quantity int
) WITH RECOMPILE as begin

    set nocount on;

    SELECT * --explicitly name columns here, not all columns in the table.
    FROM bookdat b
    WHERE title = coalesce(@title, b.title)
        OR author = coalesce(@author, b.author)
        OR publication = coalesce(@publication, b.publication)
        OR accno = coalesce(@accno, b.accno)
        OR price = coalesce(@price, b.price)
        OR quantity = coalesce(@quantity, b.quantity)

end
```

Now that we have a way to retrieve the data from the database we need to setup our dotnet code. Please notice that I am utilizing the USING statement. This is something you should be doing on object that inherit the IDisposable interface. It ensures that the object will always be properly dealt with when it falls out of scope. This is extremely important for database connections or you will overload the connection pool.

Especially since it seems like your are still learning the language you really use object names that have meaning. Just using the default numbered names is not a good practice. When you have to maintain your code in the future you will go crazy trying to remember which textbox is which when the names mean nothing.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill The Required Fields To Find Data !!");
        }
        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bookdat_Search", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox8.Text;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox8.Text;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@publication", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox8.Text;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@accno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
                            break;
                    }
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Record Found!!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found!!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right, my way of achieving it was way too complicated, even though it wasn't much required. Will stick to searching the data from this table by primary id, anyways thanks so much for helping.
And yes, i will keep in mind about avoiding Parameter.AddWithValue.
Also, i was testing out my idea, that's why didn't cared to change the textbox names, and thanks a lot again.